# How to delete first line of file in perl script

Tags: perl, header, line

How can i remove first line of txt file in perl script?

```
`sed "1d" filename.txt`
```

Dosen't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Tie::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile):

```
use Tie::File;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $filename or die $!;
shift @array;
untie @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`sed 1d filename.txt > newfile.txt`
```

should work. If you don't redirect it to a file, it will just read the whole file minus the first line to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

That sends to the output to `sed`'s STDOUT (which Perl proceeds to capture into a variable) instead of `filename.txt`. You want to use `sed`'s `-i`.

```
sed -i "1d" filename.txt
```

Since there's no output to capture, it makes no sense to use backticks. You want `system`.

```
system('sed -i "1d" filename.txt');
```

Better: (Avoids launching another shell)

```
system('sed', '-i', '1d', 'filename.txt');
```

Best: (Does error checking for you)

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( systemx );
systemx('sed', '-i', '1d', 'filename.txt');
```

Comment: "sed" failed to start: "Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego pliku" at accmaker.pl line 26.

in translate: Can not open this file

Comment: @user1100671, That means the path `filename.txt` doesn't refer to an existing file. It has nothing to do with your question

Comment: It seems pretty lame to go loading a module, and not a core one either, merely to check the return value of the `system` function.

Comment: @tchrist, It's used by core specifically for that reason. Are you saying Perl is lame? Avoiding writing the same 4 lines over and over again is not lame.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing this using an inline sed, here is a Perl equiv..

```
perl -ne'$.==1?next:print' <(seq 1 10)
```

Where the options mean,

```
-n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Other notes,

- `$.` is the variable for the current line number.
- `<()` is Bash voodoo for generating a FIFO in the background.